# Chinese symbol instead of function or ionicon icon

Tags: font-awesome, nativescript, ionicons

For some reason, I am getting Chinese symbols instead of the right icon. I have the .ttf in app/fonts directory and .css under /app. Hope that you will find my mistake

app.css

```
.fa {
    font-size: 60;
    font-family: FontAwesome, fontawesome-webfont;
}

.ion {
  font-family: Ionicons, ionicons;
  font-size: 60;
}
```

main.ts

```
import { TNSFontIconService } from 'nativescript-ng2-fonticon';

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(TranslateLoader, {
    useFactory: () => {
      return new TNSTranslateLoader('assets/i18n');
    }
  }),
  TranslateService,
  provide(TNSFontIconService, {
    useFactory: () => {
      return new TNSFontIconService({
        'fa': 'font-awesome.css',
        'ion': 'ionicons.css'
      });
    }
  })  
])
```

page.html

```
  <Button class="fa" [text]="'fa-bluetooth' | fonticon"></Button>
  <Label class="ion" [text]="'ion-flag' | fonticon"></Label>
```

page.ts

```
import { TNSFontIconService, TNSFontIconPipe } from 'nativescript-ng2-fonticon';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'pages/pages/page.html',
  pipes: [TranslatePipe, TNSFontIconPipe]
})
export class Pages {
  constructor(private fonticon: TNSFontIconService,
              private translate: TranslateService) {}
```

Comment: Is your app on android or ios? That really matters

Comment: I am using android

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is a problem with the setting the font-family property in your app.css file. When you download the custom font, you should set the same font file name to font-family without changing it.

I tested `ionicons` in a sample project and you can review it [here](https://github.com/tsonevn/NativeScriptAngular2IconFontsSample.git) in my github repo. 
In addition you could review this article: [Icon Fonts](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/icon-fonts.html)

Comment: Hi Nikolay. I don't see you using nativescript-ng2-fonticon. I don't want to use the hex value, but instead the font name. It is clearer, I think. Would you mind to try it?

Answer (score 0):

In app.css, if you are implementing on android, then the `font-family` must be the same name of the .ttf file's name. For example, you have the font file which is **fontAwesome.ttf** then the CSS should be:

```
.some-cssClass{
   font-family: fontAwesome;
}
```

However if it's iOS, you have to make sure that `font-family` is using the name of the font. Double click to **fontAwesome.tff**, you will see the name of the font: "FontAwesome" (for example), then:

```
.some-cssClass {
   font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Like you can see in my sample code, my .fa class is using both. I even added the double quotes around FontAwesome, but did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue.

I had app.css and app.android.css. All my settings for fonticon was in app.css. Because of the app.android.css, the "compiler" took the info from app.android.css instead!